# Physical open string state problem

Tags: string-theory, oscillators, quantum-states

This is a basic question in bosonic String Theory. Can someone explain what is the interpretation of the coefficients?
Since this is like the first quantized version of String theory, I would guess that A,B,C are associated with probabilities for the string to exist in that particular oscillatory state. Is that right?

[image]

Comment: It's better to use MathJax (essentially latex) instead of putting a picture of math. Having said that, indeed, you are right about the interpretation of $A,B,C$, but this is not the most interesting feature of these coefficients. You need to impose the constraint $a=1$.

Comment: Yeah, I did impose three conditions on it, which are simply the Virasoro constraints. Those give me a unique solution for A, B and C

Comment: Right, so naively you could have a state with two "-1" excitations by having some arbitrary superposition of "2 tachyons", "one massless state and one state with mass -2", and "two massless states and two tachyons". What superposition did you find solves the Virasoro constraints?